# Context-Free Grammar from language question

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am having some problems trying to work out a context-free grammar for the following language:

```
L = { a^x b^y : y>=x, y-x is odd }
```

At the moment I have the following, but that does not work completely

```
S -> aSb | Sb |epsilon
```

How do I address the `y-x is odd` aspect of this language? It is the one thing I am unsure how to do.

Comment: Similarly with how to track parity with regular languages, you need more productions to track the difference as even or odd. `S -> aSb` will always be even, so you can't accept from this production (no epsilon). However, when you read an additional `b`, it's odd and you can accept. `S -> aSb | Ab; A -> ? | epsilon`. I'll leave it up to you to fill in the `?` - what should production `A` do when it reads a `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your grammar:

```
S -> aSb | Sb |epsilon
```

This is going to generate a^x b^y with y >= x. That's pretty close but, as you have noted, fails the "y - x is odd" test.

How can we fix this? Well, if y >= x and y - x is odd, then y = x + z, where z is some positive odd number. What does this mean? It means

1. that your first production, `S -> aSb`, is perfectly fine: we need a way to add arbitrarily many a's and keep the number of b's the same.
2. that your second production, `S -> bS`, has a big problem: this allows you to add any number of b's, but you have to add an odd number of b's.
3. that your third production, `S -> epsilon`, has a big problem: this allows you not to add any more b's, but zero is not an odd number.

To fix this, we can think up a grammar for the language of odd-length strings of b's, and replace the `S` in the RHS of the production `S -> aSb`. This will be guaranteed to give you both conditions. A grammar for odd-length strings of b's:

```
B -> b | bbB
```

Combining with your grammar and getting rid of the bad productions:

```
S -> aSb | B
B -> b | bbB
```

That should do it.